# Is there a radial timepicker UI Control for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, timepicker, gauge, radial

I'm looking for a radial time picker control for a Windows Phone 8 application like the Windows 8 Alarms app or the Realarm app for Windows Phone.

Please see the below picture:

[image: Radial Picker]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything that is designed to do this out of the box.   Telerik and Syncfusion (and likely others) have radial gauges that you could likely modify to make this.  Syncfusion also has a RadialMenu, which looks similar to what you are trying to do, but I can't speak for how flexible it is.

http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radgauge-ranges-radialrange.html